# Erase the content inside the bezierPath

Tags: uibezierpath, drawingcontext

I’m working on a project that allows the user to draw anything on an image .. after the user finishes drawing . It closes the path and erase the content of image enclosed in a path and assign a new rectangular frame with a new image that can be dragged, but it only shows the content inside the erased path.
Do you have any idea how can i achieve that ? I’m new to swift ios. and i have the code to erase the content of image.

What i need is :

1. assign a new image in a resizable rectangular frame
2. move the frame to resize accordingly so that it only shows the content inside the erased region
   This is what I’m trying to do

[image: erase the content of image inside bezier Path]

[image: assign a new image in rectangular frame]

[image: the movable frame should only be visible inside the removed content of image]

Comment: *"I tried masking the bezierpath ..."* -- ***Show us*** what you tried. Don't just say *"I tried something."* Please review [ask].

Comment: You need to focus on a single task at a time. Do you already have code that is "erases the path" part of the image? Do you already have code for "dragging the rectangle corners" to resize / move it?

Comment: I have the code to erase the content of image inside the bezierPath .. 
I need the code of resizable rectangular frame

Comment: OK - learn one step at a time. Head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift user resizable view` -- you'll find lots of examples, articles, blog posts, discussions, etc.

Comment: Can you at least help me with calculating the CGRect of Erased path ?

Comment: You can use `path.bounds`

Comment: ok Thanks .. Solved it by using
   let addSize = 44.0
            let sX = userPath.cgPath.boundingBox.origin.x
            let sY = userPath.cgPath.boundingBox.origin.y
            let sW = userPath.cgPath.boundingBox.width
            let sH = userPath.cgPath.boundingBox.height
        
            DrawnRect = CGRect(x: sX-CGFloat(24), y: sY-CGFloat(24), width: sW+CGFloat(addSize), height: sH+CGFloat(addSize))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your enclosed UIBezierPath

```
let path = // ... your enclosed UIBezierPath
```

Create a CAShapeLayer with the closed path

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

Create an image layer

```
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.contents = yourImage.cgImage
```

Apply the shape layer as a mask to the image layer

```
imageLayer.mask = shapeLayer
```

**Assuming your view is `drawingView`**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(drawingView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
drawingView.drawHierarchy(in: drawingView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```